# Client-server mobile app. Where to begin for the server side?

Tags: objective-c, database, client-server

I have to create an iPhone app which displays some sentences.

I would to download these sentences from a server and save them in a local db (for example using JSON).

The user can flag a sentence as favorite and do some other stuff.

I would to give the possibility to download other sentences, updating the corresponding table in the local db.

I don't know where to begin to build the server side.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/) its quite easy to use but do it in combination of [ExpressJS](http://expressjs.com/)... This is necessary to create the server side. You can even use some PHP framework if you prefer this...

Next you can choose between HTML5 or native programming for client side... It's up to you with which one you are more familiar... I think in your case you can create an HTML5 app to get the result as you need it... But of course its even possible native on the phone it just may take longer depending on your experience

So to sum up:

- NODEJS + ExpressJS plugin
- Phonegap (if you want to use html5 to create your app) or Native SDK (like iOS sdk or Android SDK or Windows mobile SDK)